# How to check if browser add-on contacts developer?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, firewall, add-on

For desktop applications there is a firewall and determines which app can connect to the internet.
Of course internet browsers and other internet apps are always unblocked, other way they are useless.

Now we change point of view from OS->APPS and lets look same way at BROWSER->PLUGINS.

Browser is always online and how I obtain something similar to OS firewall but for the browser plugins? How I know which add-on is actually connecting to its developers server and send some data about my browsing acitvity, add-on usage and so on... ?

Comment: How can I check who downgraded this question? Is this a type of trolling from some plugin developer :) ? There is no question about that on StackOverflow and I think the importance of it is H U G E for simple awareness of privacy.

Answer (score 1):

### Read the code

Unfortunately, AFAIK you have to read the code. For example, the extension
https://github.com/m0rtem/CloudFail/ does call home. You can search for "http" in the code.

---

### Inspect the extension

On Firefox you can inspect an extension.
For example, inspect (aka debug) uBlock. You get the full dev tools on the extension's background page. Go to the "network" tab. Now for testing, go to the extension's options. Update your filter lists. Then go back to extension inspector network tab : you see all the remote calls that the extension made, at your request. But you could also see any hidden call.

---

### content security policy

Sending the user's data to a remote server is not the same thing as writing code with poor security practices, exposing the user to malicious code execution from hackers. But still, it's related.

For Firefox, the default CSP is `"script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';"` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy.

So you can read the extension's manifest.json, to see if they changed the default policy.

---

You can also search for "google analytics" in the code.

Now, be aware that on the official stores, every extension's code base is reviewed by Chrome or Mozilla, so the worst practices (like hacking) are forbidden.
[https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions/policy#II.*Security*.2F_Privacy](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions/policy#II._Security_.2F_Privacy)

Comment: So for now there is no add-on which could serve as firewall or just notifier , which plugin is contacting external machines and what data is being sent?

Comment: Just some example: if popular add-on sends the URL I am visitting with a timestamp, it can create all my browsing history in some external database. I understand it needs the URL for some other purposes but still in the backgroud this kind of database can be created. I'd just like to know which plugins actually do that at the moment..